# is it possible to rename the WSS_Logging database for sp2010?

Tags: 2010, wss-logging

This is for sp2010. I'm considering setting up another SP farm using the same back-end SQL server. Problem is, amongst other things, I'm not seeing any way to rename the WSS_Logging database. Google has not been my friend with either "move WSS_Logging" nor "rename WSS_Logging". Skimming through my SP2010 books hasn't unearthed anything either. Looking in the Central Admim didn't turn up anything other than a greyed-out text box containing WSS_Logging, but argh. Argh!

Folks, is it possible to rename the WSS_Logging database for sp2010?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to have multiple SharePoint farms in the same instance of SQL as it not only has performance risks (due to temp table thrashing) but is a management nightmare as keeping track of which database is in use by which farm becomes a significant task.

Instead, you can use the same physical SQL Server but merely create a new instance of it and install your new farm in that instance.  Your DBAs should be able to configure new instances of SQL Server in their sleep!

This also completely eliminates the need to worry about renaming databases.

Comment: We currently are doing separate instances, but I was just wondering if something could be done for WSS_Logging. I'm gathering the answer is "Nope."